# C# Chart all Y Axes same GridLine positions

Tags: c#, charts, gridlines

I have to create a Chart with .Net 4.0 and I have a problem. If the Intervals of AxisY and Intervals of AxisY2 are different, I have different gridlines.

The question is, how can I show the same gridlines in the Chart.
I show you a picture and you will understand what I need.

As you can see, the gridline by 25 AxisY2 is different as by AxisY (for example 40). So the gridlines wanna synchronize. Thanks

[image: image]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then set both at the same value or a mutiple? AxisY2 = AxisY?

Comment: yes, so i use now but i don't just want to work with multiple.